# Why does SVGR not generate a TypeScript declaration file in my esbuild configuration?

Tags: typescript, svg, types, .d.ts, esbuild

I am creating an SVG icon library in TypeScript. So far, SVGR has been terrific, but the final piece I need are the generated types to allow passing `title` and `ref` to the bundled components.

### Reproduction

I'm not sure what all may be helpful to see, so I will include a repo and some code samples. But with the following setup, svgr is creating the components from the SVG imports, but no types are generated. As a result, whenever I try to use an icon from this package, I am warned that the declaration file for it cannot be found.

POC Repo: https://github.com/yuschick/icon-demo

*src/index.ts*

```js
export { default as TestIcon } from "./svg/test.svg";
export { default as ArrowThinLeft } from './svg/arrow-thin-left.svg';
```

*package.json*

```json
{
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node esbuild.config.js",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.14.39",
    "esbuild-plugin-svgr": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

*esbuild.config.js*

```js
import esbuild from "esbuild";
import svgr from "esbuild-plugin-svgr";

esbuild.build({
    bundle: true,
    entryPoints: ["src/index.ts"],
    external: ["react"],
    format: "esm",
    // minify: true,
    outfile: "dist/index.js",
    plugins: [svgr({ titleProp: true, ref: true, expandProps: false, typescript: true })],
})
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

*tsconfig.json*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "checkJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "include": ["src", "global.d.ts"]
}
```

*global.d.ts*

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

### Expected behavior

By passing `typescript: true` into the `svgr` options, I am expecting a `index.d.tsx` file to be generated based on the generated components.

Per the SVGR docs:

> Generates .tsx files with [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) typings.

*Note:* While I am using SVGR with ESBuild, the same problem exists when trying with Rollup as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

> By passing `typescript: true` into the `svgr` options, I am expecting a `index.d.tsx` file to be generated based on the generated components.

This expectation is not correct. SVGR will only generate `.tsx` files if you specify the `typescript` option and not `.d.ts` files. From [documentation](https://react-svgr.com/docs/options/#typescript) (which you've found as well):

> ### TypeScript
>
> Generates `.tsx` files with TypeScript typings.

However, even with this option specified, SVGR won't generate `.tsx` files because you're using this within an esbuild plugin. `esbuild-plugin-svgr` under the hood utilises the `transform` function from `@svgr/core` (see [`esbuild-plugin-svgr/index.js:L4`](https://github.com/kazijawad/esbuild-plugin-svgr/blob/4b5f554e9114c3dee8864ce5ee5a3dd929f9c1ac/index.js#L4)). The [`transform` function](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/blob/main/packages/core/src/transform.ts) only transforms the SVG to JSX or TSX but never writes the output(s). [`@svgr/cli`](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/tree/main/packages/cli/) handles writing the output(s) to file(s), for example see [`@svgr/cli/src/dirCommand.ts`](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/blob/main/packages/cli/src/dirCommand.ts).

## Solution

I think you have two options:

### Separate out SVGR from esbuild, then generate a `.d.ts` file

In other words stop using `esbuild-plugin-svgr` and use `@svgr/cli` instead. You will then have to run SVGR before esbuild; either manually, chaining commands in a script or using [npm's pre-script hook](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts). Afterwards you'll have to generate a `.d.ts file`. Although, looking at [esbuild#95](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/95), it doesn't seem it's supported out of the box. You may want to explore suggestions listed there including:

- Using the TypeScript compiler to emit a declaration file (`tsc --emitDeclarationOnly`)
- Using a plugin such as [`esbuild-plugin-d.ts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-plugin-d.ts)

Your build chain may look like this at the end:

1. Generate `.tsx` files from SVGs using `@svgr/cli`.
2. Bundle using esbuild.
3. Generate `.d.ts` file, either as a separate step using `tsc` or merging with the step above using an esbuild plugin.

### Generate a `.d.ts` file from your JavaScript bundle

If for some reason you really want to keep your current build configuration you could generate a `.d.ts` file from your JavaScript bundle file with `tsc dist/index.js --declaration --allowJs --emitDeclarationOnly` (see [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html)). Caveat is TypeScript may not be able to infer all the types so you may have an incomplete type declaration file.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for this reply. A lot of good information here to follow and I am certain this will move me forward. Thank you! :)

Comment: just as an update. I have this technically working with my prebuild script using svgr/cli, build script using esbuild to bundle the results of the prebuild, then postbuild runs tsc over the bundled files. This feels a bit fragile at this moment, but what you described has gotten everything to work as expected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with svgr when trying to bundle typescript types with the rollup-plugin-dts plugin.

Solve it by creating a single icon.d.ts file:

```
import { SVGProps } from 'react';
declare const ReactComponent: (props: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => JSX.Element;
export { ReactComponent };
```

and then used the alias plugin like so:

```
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
...
      plugins: [
        alias({
          entries: [
            {
              find: /^.*\.svg$/,
              replacement: 'src/types/icon.d.ts',
            },
          ],
        }),
        dts(),
      ],
```